# Is there a simple way to learn when to use "den" or "dem"?

Tags: standard-german

The most common answer is "You need to ask: *'Wen oder was gehört der Tisch?'* or *'Wem oder was gehört der Tisch?'*".
For me it's the same. So, is there a different way to know which one to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should one necessarily learn, when a verb goes with a dative object and when with accusative one?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/should-one-necessarily-learn-when-a-verb-goes-with-a-dative-object-and-when-wit) See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47756/general-rule-s-for-finding-out-whether-an-object-is-accusative-or-dative

Comment: I think the was, wen, wem, wer rule is probably meant for native speakers, because they've developed an intuition for knowing which case to use without having to think about it (usually). For the rest of us I think the short answer is no, there is no simple way.

Comment: What do you suggest on how to learn it?